# Adobe AIR+AJAX ftp library

Tags: air

I have just started creating an Adobe AIR+AJAX app which will need to upload and download files from the server using ftp functionality. Right now what is happening is I need to use sockets for this which is way to confusing and difficult to maintain. So, I was wondering if anybody has developed a javascript library or functionality for ftp?

I don't want to rely on any serverside script for this. There is an ftp library for flex but it is quite confusing with not much documentation.

Can anybody help? Thanks,

Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently looking for the same thing. So far all I've found is [IntegralFTP](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/integralftp/overview.html), which looks fairly comprehensive. The catch is it's $399 for a single developer license.

Comment: I believe that integralftp needs a java applet to work and in AIR java might not work. I have abandoned AIR for Titanium. So, I am using their sockets for creating a library.

Titanium is much more powerful and only made for non-flash guys (Ruby, PHP, Python and JS).

Visit www.titaniumapp.com

Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

http://maliboo.pl/projects/FlexFTP/